# How to send email once a day?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Public sub RunAutoTasks()  
    '. 
    '.  
    '.  
    'schedules a few macros to run 
    '.  
    scheduleTime = TimeValue("15:00:00")
    Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "DailyEmail"  
    
End Sub  
      

Public Sub DailyEmail()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim Mail As New Message
    Dim Config As Configuration
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim objFileSystem As Object

    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set sheetHome = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("START")
    'Turns off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     'Makes a copy of the active sheet and save it to
     'a temporary file
    filename = Range("Sheet_Name") & "_" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh_mm") & ".xlsm"
    filepath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        
    objFileSystem.copyfile ThisWorkbook.FullName, filepath & filename
    
    Set Config = Mail.Configuration
    
    Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "xxxxxx"
    Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
    Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = False
    Config(cdoSendUserName) = "xxxxx"
    Config(cdoSendPassword) = "xxxxxxx"
    Config.Fields.Update
     
    Mail.AddAttachment (filepath & filename)
    
    Mail.To = sheetHome.Range("EmailAddress").Value
    Mail.From = Config(cdoSendUserName)
    Mail.Subject = "Daily report for " & sheetHome.Range("Sheet_Name").Value
    Mail.HTMLBody = "Workbooks for Daily review<p>" & _
    "Thanks<p>" & _
    "This is an automated email, please don't reply to this email."
    
    Mail.Send
   
    Set Mail = Nothing
    Set Config = Nothing
    LogEvent "Event", " :Sent daily email at" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm")
     Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "DailyEmail", , False
Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    LogEvent "Error", "Sub: DailyEmail | " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo -1
End Sub
```

Even after I unschedule it in the `DailyEmail` sub it gets called multiple times and sends email multiple times.

Outlook could not be configured in those computers so I used CDO. It does work as email is getting sent.

The workbook stays open a few days and during those days I need to send email once a day to the supervisors.

RunAutoTasks is scheduled to run every 30 mins and the application.ontime for DailyEmail is set as well. I parameterized timevalue() even then the email is getting sent multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Always keep the time value in a global variable.
When you unschedule `Now()` that may actually be one second too late and the unschedule does not work.

It seems there is an issue that the scheduled events are called multiple times and thus means the DailyMail function is called multiple times.
We can solve that with a Public variable and have that set to true the first time the schedule is set.
And before we set a schedule we make sure this is boolean is not true.

```
Public scheduleTime as Date
Public SetTime as Boolean

Public sub RunAutoTasks()  
    'schedules a few macros to run 
    scheduleTime = TimeValue("15:00:00")
    If SetTime = False then Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "DailyEmail"  
    SetTime = True
End Sub  
  
Public Sub DailyEmail()  
    'send email code  
    Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "DailyEmail", , False  
End Sub
```

Comment: should scheduleTime be string, I don't think Time is a valid datatype?

Comment: Yes you are right I messed up. It should be Date

Comment: That didn't do it. Do I need to close and open the excel after modifying the code?

Comment: Didn't do what?

Comment: @Iswar you need to run the `RunAutoTasks` procedure once after the workbook was opened  (and before `15:00`) to trigger the launch at `15:00`. Make sure you have some code like a `Debug.Print` or a `MsgBox` in your `DailyEmail` procedure to verify if the procedure launched or not (as there might be errors in your `'send email code` which make you assume the procedure didn't launch).

Comment: @Andreas it didn't stop sending multiple emails at the scheduled time.

Comment: @Peh RunAutoTasks is called every half hr. and DailyEmail procedure is referenced at that time. That doesn't seem like a problem.

Comment: If you call the function every half an hour, that could be an issue
. I have never tried that but I can see that causing issues if the schedules just 'pile up'. As a test set a schedule at some time, then do it again. Then try and unschedule twice. If you get an error message the second time that means only one scheduled event was created. If you don't get an error you have two events firing at the same time. This test can be done in the immediate window if you want.

Comment: @Andreas you are right, the email schedule is piling up. Like you said I unscheduled it twice and it did not throw an error.

Comment: @Iswar In that case have a look at my edited answer

Comment: @Andreas If SetTime = False then Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "DailyEmail" and not SetTime<>False right?

Comment: @Iswar yes, looks better ;)

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what you get when you type answers from the phone.

Comment: @Andreas Now I get Error 1004: Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed right at unschedule

Comment: That is probably because you have no scheduled time.